# Group isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

In general how would one show that two groups are isomorphic?

I know that to show that they aren't you would try to show that some abstract property is not satisfied, such as they have different orders etc.

I can't see a straightforward way of showing that they are isomorphic though.

Comment: Exhibit an isomorphism

Comment: Well, generally speaking, this is not such an easy thing to do. However, in practice, one often writes down a bijective homomorphism between the two groups in question. Sometimes, there is an easy way to do this; sometimes not. The so-callled ''First Isomorphism Theorem'' for groups is often helpful in these situations.